# When creating a Copy Activity in an Azure Data Factory pipeline, how do I map a CSV sheet with 5 columns to a CSV sheet with 20 columns?

Tags: csv, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

So I have an input CSV sheet that I want to copy into an output CSV sheet. The output CSV sheet has all the columns in the input sheet, plus a bunch of other columns. (I will be copying data into those from other input sheets later.)

When I run the pipeline containing my Copy Activity, the only columns present in the new output sheet are the 5 columns from the input sheet, I assume because those are the only ones in the mapping. However, I've also tried creating 15 "Additional Columns" in the "source" section of the Copy Activity --- just trying out things like "test", \"test\", test, @test, @pipeline().DataFactory, $$FILEPATH, etc. --- but when I debug the pipeline and go back to my container and look at the output sheet, still only the 5 columns from the input sheet are present there!

How do I get the output sheet to contain columns that are not present in the input sheet? Do I need to create an ARM template?

I am doing this entirely via the Azure Portal, btw.

Comment: Have you try my answer? Any problem?

Answer (score 0):

This will be much easier to design in ADF's data flows instead by creating Derived Columns to append to your output sink schema

Answer (score 0):

This works fine on my side. Is there any differences?

[image]

[image]

[image]